# Regular local ring result - reference request

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra

Reference needed for the following result:

> Let $R$ be a regular local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$. If $A$ is a flat $R$-algebra and $A/(\mathfrak m)$ is a domain, then $A$ is a domain.

Comment: @ref What do you mean by $(\mathfrak m)$? Is it somehow the ideal generated by $\mathfrak m$ in $A$, that is, $\mathfrak mA$?

Answer (score 1):

This is not true: consider $A=R\times K$ where $K$ is the field of fractions of $R$.

But if you assume $A\otimes_R K$ (instead of $A/\mathfrak m A$) is a domain, then $A$ is indeed a domain by flatness: $A\to A\otimes_R K$ is injective. And this has nothing to do with regularity of $R$.